# unix bash string search without using awk or sed

Tags: string, bash, shell, unix, search

Can't use awk or sed or any other string processing utilities

Any help on this problem is appreciated I have a text file with the following format

```
BobJanitor20000
TedBuilder30000
NedFighter25000
KitTeacher40000
```

yes, assume that the names are always three characters long, profession 7 characters and salary 5 characters edit: varaibles come from user input and not as a parameters

I ask the user for a name input and another input whether to display occupation or Salary

If the user enters "Ted" and chooses salary, the output should be

```
Ted 30000
```

The program must also take into account partial name matches, "ed" and salary should output

```
Ted 30000
Ned 25000
```

I know cut and grep can get me the relavent lines but how do i create the output i want?

cut -c1-3 textFile| grep "$user_input"

gets me the lines i want to use but how do i isolate the Name and profession columns and then the name and salary columns

Comment: Why the restriction for `awk`, `sed`?

Comment: Better show what you tried so far. This looks like homework and you should be the one doing it : )

Comment: yes this is homework, as for what i tried, i feel this is a knowledge issue that you either know or don't. I know that cut and a grep will get me the lines i want but i'm stuck there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must split the input lines in fields first. Something like `grep "$user_input" textFile` will fail when the input matches a part of the job. 
For this reason a simple approach with grep will fail:

With grep you have the option -o to show the matching part only. Combine this with a dot for a single character, and `^` for the beginning of a line or a `$` for the end of the line.

```
# Show salary
# echo "TedBuilder30000" | grep "Ted" | grep -o ".....$"
# Show job
# echo "TedBuilder30000" | grep "Ted" | grep -o "............$" | grep -o "^......."
```

This will become messy when you want to show the matched name (Ted/Ned) as well.

So how do we split everything up?
I already stored the userinput for name and display in variables. The display is converted in lowercase automaticly with the `typeset -l`.

```
userinput=ed
typeset -l display
display=Salary
while read line; do
        # offset 0, length 3
        name=${line:0:3}
        job=${line:3:7}
        sal=${line:10:5}
        # echo "Debug: Name=$name Job=$job Sal=$sal"
        # double brackets for matching the userinput with wildcards
        if [[ "$name" = *${userinput}* ]]; then
                # Use case for a switch between different possible values
                case "${display}" in
                "occupation|job") echo "${name} ${job}";;
                "salary") echo "${name} ${sal}";;
                *) echo "Unsupported display ${display}";;
                esac
        fi
done < testFile # While reads from testFile, I avoid using cat (Google for uuoc)
```

Answer (score -1):

You may want:

```
grep "$user_input" textFile | tee >(cut -c '11-15') | echo `cut -c 1-2`
```

This is called process substitution.

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28503/how-can-i-send-stdout-to-multiple-commands

Answer (score -2):

You can use `cut` with character ranges, for example

```
echo NedFighter25000 | cut -c 1-3
```

Comment: cut -c 1-3 textFile | grep "$input" can get me the relavent lines but how exactly do i isolate the name and profession columns or the name and salary columns?